# Mask a {Common:ItemURL} in Nintex workflow

Tags: html, sharepoint, nintex-workflow

I have a form library in SharePoint 2013 with form names that have an ID appended to the end of the name, so it appears to be "Form Name-26". My customer does not want the "26" to display.

So, I have been trying to create a workflow that will start whenever a form is created. It can pull the Item URL without any problem, but then I want to 'mask' the URL. I was trying to use anchor tags within the "Set Item Value" workflow action, but this actually displayed everything and didn't read the html.

Here is the code I am trying to get to work.

```
<a href:ItemURL>Click here to open the form</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out the answer to my own question.

I created a calculated column in SharePoint and set the data type to number.

Then I put in the following:

```
="<a href='Beginning of Link"&[Str Filename]&"'/>"&Year&" "&Department&"</a>"
```

This ends up 'masking' the link with the Year and Department (2 other fields I have in my library) and using the filename for the form in the link so that it dynamically changes for each item.